# How can I get virtual machines specifications from Google cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-compute-api

I would like to know if there is a way to collect the technical specifications of a virtual machine from Google Cloud (CPU, frequency, memory, storage) ?
I am using the billing API (https://cloudbilling.googleapis.com/v1/services/6F81-5844-456A/skus?key=API_KEY) to get the pricing information but there is no technical specifications.

Is there a way to get that data ? May be using the products' SKU or something ? I know AWS and Azure SDKs/APIs allows developers to get the technical information but I did not find the GCP equivalent for this.

I searched for a while for something like this but it seems like a lot of people had the same issue but no one had a working answer.

Answer (score 1):

The compute API offers you several operations that you can use to obtain the desired information.

Especially consider review the [`instances` `get` operation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/get), it will provide you all the [details](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances) of the instance.

You can obtain the list of instances in a certain zone if required using the [`instances` `list` operation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/list).

If you are trying to obtain information about [machines families](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types), GCP provides a rich [API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/machineTypes) as well.

Comment: I try to use the instances.list operation, via [their website](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/list), but I have, as response, only `kind, id and selfLink`, but no `items`. I use the project id of the project created by default when you create a GCP account, and `europe-west1-b` as region. Is there something I am missing ?

Comment: Hi @Scryper. Sorry for the late reply. Thank you for the feedback. And, have you deployed VMs in that project/zone? As an alternative to the API you could try the `gcloud` cli. [This is the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/list) for the `compute instances list` operation. Please, could you try? You don't need to install the CLI, you can use Cloud Shell through the GCP Web console if you wish.

Comment: Hi, no worries. Unfortunately, when I wrote this post I did not know that the API only send those informations for the VM you actually pay for. What I want to do, is to get the information for all the vms that GCP offers. For the moment, my research showed that there is no such thing. I hope I missed something, and there is such an API, if you know about it, please share that information :). If not, no worries, thanks for your time and answers !

Comment: Hi @Scryper. Every major public cloud provider offers you that functionality. Then, I think you are actually looking for the different machine images you can use. Please, consider review the provided [API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/machineImages); the `gcloud` [exposes](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/machine-images) the same functionality as well. Please, could you try? I hope it helps.